# How do I add data output to my table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written the following query in postgresql:

```
select log10(x) as x
   , log10(y) as y
   , log10(z) as z
from table;
```

This changes the values in my table into log10's of their original values.

In the data output panel, everything looks fine, so I just have to add it to my table.

Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything that does what I want to accomplish?

I have tried ALTER TABLE just under the first code lines like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table
   add x numeric
   , add y numeric
   , add z numeric
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "table"

Any other way to add the log10 columns to the original table?

Comment: Is your table called `table`? Don;t you already have columns called x, y,z? if youdo you can't add the same named columns again. What is the current sturcture, and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: Hello @tinazmu, no the table has an other name, and the columns as well. I just didn't post the names here, so I used x,y, and z.

I want to add these columns to my table after putting them in the log10() function. I can see the new values of the records in my data output panel, but I don't know how to go om from there.

Comment: I am trying to understand if you are attempting to replace the values in existing columns with their Log10 values (ie the columns already exist) in this case you would use `UPDATE`, or if you want to add new columns with log10 values of existing columns (then the data is considered redundant), in this case you could use `ALTER TABLE <tbl> ADD` to add empty columns, followed by `UPDATE` to set the values. Which one is it?

Comment: @tinazmu I was trying to achieve the second method. So to add more columns to my table without updating the old values. If that is complicated I'm also happy with just updating the original columns with the log10 values.

Comment: If the SELECT statement works then you already have those three columns and you can not add them (again). Btw: the SELECT statement does not _change_ the column values, it only _displays_ them as a different value.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you already have columns `x`, `y`, and `z`. In that case, you will not be able to add additional columns with the same names. Instead, you must do one of three things:

1. `UPDATE` the table in place. No new column additions: just update the values of the columns you have. In this case, the original values are lost, and nothing is done to support new data as it arrives.
2. `ALTER` the table to add the new [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html), but use *different names*. In this case, the new columns are *redundant*, because the existing columns already have everything you need to generate the values whenever you want them. And if the table is really named `table`, make sure to properly account for the fact "table" is a **reserved word**.
3. Create a `View`. The original table is unchanged, but now you have a View in the database you can SELECT from when you want to use the logarithmic values instead.

Of these, I find it likely option 3 is most appropriate, but without more details it's hard to know